# object variable is not getting updated in Golang

Tags: oop, go

I have created a struct `Person` and a method `AddPerson` which acts as a constructor for that struct.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    name string
    salary int
    balance int
}

func AddPerson(name string, salary int) Person {
    p := Person{}
    p.name = name
    p.salary = salary
    p.balance = salary

    return p
}
```

After that I added a method `spendMoney` which does the following:

```
func (p Person) spendMoney(amountSpent int) {
    p.balance = p.salary - amountSpent
    fmt.Println("The amount spent is : ", amountSpent)
    fmt.Println("Balance left is : ", p.balance)
}
```

and a `main` method shown below:

```
func main(){
    p1 := AddPerson("A", 1500)
    p2 := AddPerson("B", 2000)
    p1.spendMoney(500)
    p2.spendMoney(1000)
    fmt.Println(p1.balance) //wanted to check the balance of p1 after spending.
}
```

I wanted to check the balance of p1 after he has spent the money, but it is still showing the same as before (i.e. 1500). I am new to Golang and come from a Python background, where this way works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the method on a pointer to your object, not to the value of your object.

```golang
func (p *Person) spendMoney(amountSpent int) {
    p.balance = p.salary - amountSpent
}
```

Contrary to Python, you have to make the distinction between *values* and [*pointers*](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1). *Values* are basically copies of variables, modifying them will not make the variable itself change, unless explicitly assigning a new value to that variable.
[This tutorial](https://tour.golang.org/methods/4) may make you better understand this.

Comment: Thank You! That worked perfectly.